# Is there a way to add more locations as pokestops in pokemon go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I used to watch many pokemon go fan videos from US or other countries on Youtube. Most of them have so many pokestops like this image below.

[image: PokeStops in Game Map].

People who live around that region have a good opportunity to grasp free goodies from game and also they can trigger lure module to lure pokemons on these pokestops. So many advantages to have so many pokestops around.

I live in Chandigarh, India, game is not released here yet, but like most of the world, Pokemon Go is very famous here as well.

Let me tell you a little about Chandigarh. Chandigarh is also known as City Beautiful and City of Gardens. There are so many tourist attractions, parks, sculptures, etc.

We don't have so many pokestops here. So I can consider that we are having a little disadvantage. Guess we are not active on Google Map. Two days ago I been to few places, and I found that there'r few Religious places which are marked as pokestop but not all. No collage campus or School are marked.

So I was wondering, Is there a way to get them all on as Pokestops in Pokemon Go?

Comment: I wonder why that topic never appeared on my search when i was adding my question title. Care to tell me How can I improve my search here? I don't want to get my questions tagged as "duplicate"!!

Comment: @Hemant sadly, the search feature on StackExchange is kinda crap.  Whenever I need to look for a previous answer, I will google for the following: site:gaming.stackexchange.com "[keywords]"

Comment: That was one of the top question when I searched just `add pokestop`. Being closed as duplicate _is not_ a bad thing, nor are you punished from it. You get a ready answer to your question, as will anybody who happens to find your question in stead. (Once the question gets closed, there will be a link to the duplicate at the top.)

Comment: using the site: code restricts the google search to that site, and "quotes" forces only returns with that excate word in it.  If nothing is found, Google will try without quotes for synonyms to that word.

Comment: @DJPirtu. Thanks for replying. Some people mark the question with negative points and that is like a punishment. :(. Anyway. I checked the link you provided. It seems Niantic is not accepting new pokestop requests at this moment. Thanks.

Comment: That is an unfortuante side effect, but shouldn't be too bad. In fact, the faster the question gets handeled, the faster those should stop as well.

Comment: It's now impossible to ask for a new Pokestop : https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221968408-Reporting-Pok%C3%A9Stop-or-Gym-Issues "we are currently not accepting submissions for new PokéStops or Gyms"

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is no way to create pokestops or gyms, Niantic (the company that made Pokemon go) previously made a game named ingress, it had the same concept as Pokemon go. After the game had been out for a while, you were able to suggest portals (the equivalent of pokestops), thus far I do expect it to be a feature in a further update as well an many other players, for now only Niantic can add pokestops and gyms. It is a disadvantage for players living in these areas, so that is most definetally one of the company's biggest priorities.